# Django and ajax problem cannot show results from query in template

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, templates

I'm developing a website in django and at the moment i'm trying to implement search by using ajax.
Currently i'm getting results in console but i cannot show results in the template.

views.py

```
def search_products(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    search_str = json.loads(request.body).get('searchText')

    products = Product.objects.filter(Q(price__istartswith=search_str) | 
       Q(name__icontains=search_str) | Q(description__icontains=search_str))
    data = products.values()
    return JsonResponse(list(data), safe=False)
```

urls.py

```
path('search-products/', csrf_exempt(views.search_products), name="search_products"),
```

searchProducts.js

```
const appTable = document.querySelector(".app-table");
tableOutput.style.display = "none";

searchField.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
    const searchValue = e.target.value;

    if (searchValue.trim().length > 0) {
         fetch("/search-products/", {
            body: JSON.stringify({ searchText: searchValue }),
            method: "POST",
        })
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((data) => {
                console.log("data", data);
                appTable.style.display = "none";
                tableOutput.style.display = "block";

                if (data.length === 0) {
                    tableOutput.innerHTML = 'No Results Found';            
        
                }
            });
    }else {
        tableOutput.style.display = "none";
        appTable.style.display = "block";
    }
});
```

template

```
<div class="container-3 w-container">
  <div class="search-block w-form">
    <form id="email-form-2" name="email-form-2" data-name="Email Form 2" class="search-field">
      <label for="name-3" class="search-label-2">Search:</label>
        <input type="text" class="searchfield w-input" name="name-2" data-name="Name 2" placeholder="" id="searchField">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="w-layout-grid grid-8 table-output">
  <div id="w-node-_16f775a1-c8df-749b-d74e-d96c0e9465bf-488447d3" class="search-product-result">
    <a href="#" class="w-inline-block"><img src="images/search-results.jpeg" loading="lazy" height="" width="237" sizes="100vw" alt=""></a>
    <div class="div-block-33">
      <a href="#" class="link-2-product-price search">Product Title</a>
      <a href="#" class="link-2-product-price search">€ 500</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can i show results in template by using image, product title and price from server?

Please kindly give me a hint on how to proceed.
Many Thanks

[image: Data]

Comment: Hi, can you show output of `data` ?

Comment: Hi Swati! I've updated question with data. Thank you! :)

Comment: Did you tried simply looping through json datas and then generating that htmls inside that loop ?

Comment: Hi Swati! No haven't tried what you suggest. How can i do that?

Comment: Hi Swati, i've managed to do it with another way and it is working. Thank you for your time!